# Double preposition?

Tags: prepositions

I am reading a journal and found a sentence which seems wrong. The sentence is,

> It  is apparent  that  the errors originate from outside the model.

This sentence used from and outside together which are supposed to be preposition here. I guess double preposition is not allowed in the English Grammar. May someone clarify this point for me? Moreover, I rewrote the sentence. May anyone check whether my modification makes the sentence correct?

**The modified sentence:**

> 1.) It is apparent that the errors originate outside the model.
>       2.) It is apparent that the errors originate from the outside of the model.

Any help are appreciated!

**UTC +8:00 12/13/2013 4:05 PM**

**Follow-up question:**

So double preposition is not incorrect. But in this example, it seems redundant to use "from outside". Like my 1st alternative, just "outside" is enough to express all the meaning. Should we avoid double preposition in this case? Or does it express some specific meaning that I have not understood yet?

Comment: Who told you *double preposition is not allowed in the English Grammar?* That's complete nonsense - there's nothing wrong with *errors originating **from outside** the model* (or indeed [*voices **from beyond** the grave*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22voices+from+beyond+the+grave%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Your rephrased version #2 is cumbersome, and introduces unhelpful associations with *the outer surface of the physical boundary of something.*

Comment: So how to determine whether a double preposition is correct? Is it like idiom?

Comment: I wouldn't call it idiomatic so much as context-dependent. It often happens with phrasal verbs: _I'll call her up on the walkie-talkie_, or _I'll look it up in the newspaper_, e.g. ("call up" and "look up" are phrasal verbs, so those aren't really dual prepositions). The original sentence is fine; _originate from_ functions as a single unit, and _outside the model_ is a place where errors can originate from.

Comment: “from within” is fairly common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't recognise the idea that there might be something wrong with "double prepositions" in English. Obviously it's not true in general, but I can't even guess why anyone would think it true in *any* context.

For the specific usage OP asks about, it's just a matter of whether we normally speak of things *originating somewhere*, or *originating **from** somewhere*. As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=originate%20from%20the%20outside,originate%20from%20outside,originate%20outside&year_start=1960&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,originate%20from%20the%20outside;,c0;.t1;,originate%20from%20outside;,c0;.t1;,originate%20outside;,c0) shows, we actually use the first form 2-3 times more often, but there's nothing wrong with the second in *originate **from** outside*.

That NGram also shows how rarely we use OP's suggested *originate **from the** outside*. What this *doesn't* tell you is that ***the*** outside would be extremely unlikely in OP's exact context, because when we include the article before *outside*, we're normally referring to *the outer surface* (of a container, for example).

Comment: But I wonder if it is redundant to use double preposition at most of the case. As you can see, modified sentence 1 can express the same thing by using one preposition. Moreover, some double preposition is obviously wrong, for example, "The apple is in on the table.". Are there any rule to determine whether a double preposition is correct?

Comment: @user2720402: To repeat - your entire concept of double prepositions being "wrong" seems unhelpful to me. There's nothing inherently wrong with *"The apple is in on the table"*. I really think it would be better for you to forget you ever heard of this "rule", since it doesn't seem to reflect any aspect of English I know about. Besides which, it's causing you to reject valid constructions and invent your own "unlikely" alternatives, so it's actually more of a hindrance than a help.

Comment: @FumbleFingers wait, what does "The apple is in on the table" mean?

Comment: @Jan: It just means the location of the apple can be described as both *in [there]* (i.e. - somewhere that the speaker is "outside" of), and *on [the table]* (i.e. - the table is underneath the apple, holding it up above the floor). In practice that particular sequence might not be said very often, but there's nothing in the "rules of grammar" saying you can't string together multiple [prepositions of place](http://www.grammar.cl/rules/prepositions-of-place.htm)...

Comment: ...if you want a different example, here are plenty of written instances (with ***three*** consecutive prepositions) of ["up above in the"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22up+above+in+the%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: The best available answer.

Comment: The "man is in on the joke" but I don't think the "apple is in on the table".

Comment: @Nigel: Because your comment "pinged" me to revisit this one, I couldn't resist googling ["four consecutive prepositions"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22four+consecutive+prepositions%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&oq=%22four+consecutive+prepositions%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.598778529j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I'm a bit dubious about the mythical schoolboy asking the teacher *What did you lock the book that you read to us **out of up for**?*, but *Why don't you come **on over down to** my house?* sounds "almost" plausible.

Comment: ...but I don't have a huge problem with *It's in on the table* (where ***in*** implies ***in there*** or ***indoors***, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong about this, but that *outside* in *"It is apparent that the errors originate from **outside** the model,"* makes me read it as a noun, i.e.

> Where does those errors originate from?
>   It is apparent that the errors originate from (outside the model).

Aside from being a preposition, [**outside**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/outside) can be an adjective, an adverb, and a noun.

In some occasions, we cannot omit *from* before *outside*. For example, imagine some two workers gossiping about a new guy who moved to their branch a few days ago.

> Where did he come from? (He is so hot!)
>   You don't know? He came from outside (of our company).

Obviously, without that *from*, the meaning will be totally different.

Comment: I don't think the word "outside" in the original sentence acts as a noun. It's strange. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: I think we can interpret it both way. I didn't think of it as a noun until I saw your *... from the outside of the model.*

Answer (score 1):

It's not illegal to have double prepositions in English.

The reason the sentence makes sense is that `outside the model` is a preposition phrase which is acting as a noun.  It would make perfect sense to say, for example, `It is apparent that the errors originate from the kitchen.`  Here the noun is `outside the model` instead of `the kitchen.`

I will mention that *stylistically* many would argue that it is more concise to simply say `outside`.  But grammatically it is definitely not incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> It is apparent that the errors originate **from** ***outside*** *the model*.

This is a perfectly valid sentence.

Contrary to the traditional grammar, according to the modern grammar a preposition can take a wide range of grammatical structures as complement. For example:

> **1.** It hasn't been [***until*** recently] that they have had to put on their big boy pants and actually go after him. [AdvP as complement]
>
> **2.** [***From*** behind the cloud] appeared the moon.* [PP as complement]
>
> **3.** Please drop the garbage [***into*** the dustbin]. [NP as complement]
>
> **4.** They took me [***for*** dead]. [AdjP as complement]
>
> **5.** They are the experts [***on*** whether their lives are worth living]. [Embedded interrogative clause as complement]
>
> **6.** He left [***before*** the meeting ended]. [Clause as complement]

Though not all prepositions can license all the grammatical structures listed above. For example the preposition "from" can't take any AdvP, but another preposition — "until" — can.

<sub>* [Traditional grammar will call it the occurrence of double preposition. According to the traditional grammar a noun or a noun phrase can sit in the complement position of a preposition. But what about **until recently**? I have grown up reading traditional grammar, but I haven't found any satisfactory explanation for **until recently**. So I readily accepted the explanation of Modern Grammar.]</sub>

So in your quoted sentence ***from*** outside the model is a PP, where **from** is the head preposition, and it takes another PP — *outside the model* — as complement. In *outside the model*, the head preposition is *outside*, and the complement is a NP — *the model*.

Why is **outside** in *outside the model* not a noun?

There are examples of nouns that can act like an adjective as in *ice cream* etc; they are known as [noun adjuncts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). In the order of adjectives such adjectives sit exactly before the head noun. In the NP structure the order is *Determiner + Adjective + head noun*. No other ordering is possible. In *outside the model*, if we consider *outside* as noun, the structure is incorrect as the central determiner — *the* — is placed in the middle of that NP structure.

Why is **outside** in *outside the model* not an adjective?

Consider the following sentence:

> *Unaware of the consequences*, John made this decision.

Here *unaware the consequence* is an AdjP, and it predicates the noun — *John*. As it's an AdjP it needs an NP to predicate upon. Hence the following sentence is incorrect:

> *!Unaware of the consequence*, there was the decisions that was made. (INCORRECT)

Now see this:

> *Outside the model*, there is no existence of the theory.

This makes a valid sentence, and the phrase *outside the model* does not need an NP to predicate on. So it's clear that it's not an AdjP. In your sentence also it is not hinged to any NP.

Why is **outside** in *outside the model* not an adverb, but a preposition?

*outside* here takes NP as complement, and that confirms that it's not an adverb, but a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

- The cat came out from under the bed.

English has no problem with a double preposition like "from under" and similar combinations. They are just shortenings as in

- The cat came out from (her place/a place) under the bed.

Similar: He jumped out from behind a dustbin.