# is "from within you ", two successive prepositions possible?

Tags: prepositions

> forgetting about those subjective misgivings that arise from within
>   you

I was reading an passage and that phrase was in there. I couldn't understand
exact meaning because of that "from" and "within".

What do they mean and which case can two prepositions be natural?

Comment: I think this is a possible duplicate of this http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/82041/3463

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From denotes a direction and modifies the verb.

Within means locality and modifies the object.

Basically, the combination of "from" ***and*** "within" together is redundant here, because "from" can subsume "within" *or* "arise" can subsume "from", but repetition is a valid stylistic choice to clarify details or just to add emphasis.

The reason this double preposition might seem wrong to you is that often enough a combined single preposition might seem more natural. Hence formations like *into*, *onto*, *roundabout* ... and plain omission in *go home* (where home is an adverbial object) instead of "go to home".

Compare [*from outside vs outside* double preposition](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14318/double-preposition?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the debatable *get off of that horse* [e.g.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-can-i-explain-to-people-that-the-phrase-off-of-is-grammatically-incorrect) The former suggests *arise within you* being more common.

Comment: I'm sure it's not what you intended, but saying that ***from** and **within** are redundant here* might be misunderstood as meaning *both* prepositions are redundant, and could thus be discarded. The reality is that you could discard *one or the other*, but not both. Note that there's nothing wrong with stringing even more prepositions together, as in [*He got **up out of** bed*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22got+up+out+of%22) (that's tens of thousands of written instances in Google Books).

Comment: I edited to expand the point a bit more before adding my upvote. Not my greatest edit, I agree (I'm not great at using different fonts, quoted strings, etc.), but I hope it's clearer now.