# is it okay to say "Please go get it under the bed for me"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, idioms

> [get](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get) [transitive] to go to a place and bring somebody/something back
>   SYNONYM fetch
>
> get somebody/something Quick—go and get a cloth!
>
> Somebody get a doctor!
>
> She went to get help.
>
> I have to go and get my mother from the airport (= collect her).
>
> get something for somebody Get a drink for John.
>
> get somebody/yourself something Get John a drink.

You found out that your child "**threw your T-shirt under the bed**" (not sure if it is ok to say like that), would you say "**go get it under the bed for me, please**"?

The part "**get it under the bed**" sounds a bit awkward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to say “go get it **from** under the bed”.

It may seem weird that there are two prepositions here, but this is common in English. See also the question [Double preposition?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/14318/41273)

Here’s a similar [example from a book](https://books.google.com/books?id=G3s5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT35&lpg=PT35&dq=%22get%20it%20from%20under%20the%20bed%22&source=bl&ots=Dcw8cqZvvk&sig=ACfU3U1c2dpGAgoZ2rN4ysiRC-34HuUrbQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMtrqT6tzoAhUDVt8KHXn5AFEQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ):

> I say as I get up to go get it from under the bed in the master bedroom.